# Why is my gradient sublayer displaying weirdly?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to add a gradient to a View in a custom table cell. However, it's displaying weirdly, as if it hasn't got the right CGRect from the container.

First, I have the label and its surrounding box hooked up to properties label & labelContainer respectively.

[image]

I've defined a gradient function:

```
func gradient(view: UIView) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    return gradient
}
```

And in the cellForRowAt, I have:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> ShoppingListCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customShoppingListCell", for: indexPath) as! ShoppingListCell

    cell.label.text = categories![indexPath.section].items.filter(predicate)[indexPath.row].title

    cell.labelContainer.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(view: cell.labelContainer), at:0)

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}
```

But the resulting table looks like this:

[image]

It's all a bit weird and inconsistent.

Comment: Move the gradient code in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method

Comment: I already tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple issues...

1) Cells are reused - You are adding a new subLayer every time you request the cell. That's why you're seeing multiple gradient layers on your cells.

2) Layers do not "auto-resize" with the views, so you need to update the layer frame anytime the cell frame changes. And on init, the cell frame is not (necessarily) set yet.

You'll probably find it much easier to use a subclassed `UIView` with the gradient "built-in" instead of trying to add it when configuring the cells.

Give this a try...

Create a custom `UIView` that will control the gradient, and set the Class of your `labelContainer` to that new subclass. (You won't need to make it an IBOutlet, because you won't need to modify it at runtime.)

Here is a simple example. Note that by making the new `UIView` subclass `@IBDesignable`, it will also show up in your storyboard.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class SampleGradientView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let gradientLayer = layer as! CAGradientLayer
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0)
    }

}

class ShoppingListCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

}

class GradTableCellsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var catTitles = [
        "Meat & Fish",
        "Fruit & Veg",
        "Dairy"
    ]

    var catData = [
        ["Steak"],
        ["Apricot", "Asparagus"],
        ["Milk"]
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = 56.0

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return catTitles.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return catData[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customShoppingListCell", for: indexPath) as! ShoppingListCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.label.text = catData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Storyboard:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ok, this works for me. So, in the previous answers, I was told to put the code in the cell's layoutSubviews(), but this only goes one level deep, i.e. it affects its child layers but not all descendent layers. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking... this is a way to use a `UIView` subclass with a "built-in" gradient layer. Are you planning on adding other subLayers to the gradient view?

Comment: No, just trying to understand it properly.

Comment: Is there another way of knowing when the view has been resized?

Comment: If you *need* to know when it's been resized (generally you don't, if you're using auto-layout), then yes, you want to make use of `layoutSubviews()`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `cell.labelContainer.layer.masksToBounds = true` its should help

Comment: That removed the bottom lip, but there's still that gray gap on the right

Comment: call this cell.labelContainer.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(view: cell.labelContainer), at:0)
inside  layoutSubviews

Comment: this happens because constraints are not calculated yet

Comment: Doesn't change the outcome

Comment: don't forget to call super.layoutSubviews()

Comment: :( still got that weird gray bit on the edge